# Remove quotations from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array which includes unnecessary quotations ("):

```
array(["'sf64user_Number__c':'tKey'",
 "'PreferredFirstName__c':'tPreferredFirstName'"], dtype=object)
```

How can I go about removing the opening and closing "s so my numpy result would read as follows:

```
['sf64user_Number__c':'tKey', 'PreferredFirstName__c':'tPreferredFirstName']
```

BTW, my list includes 30 entries but I'm showing only two entires here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The double quotes are not part of the strings. Only the single quotes are (and you say you want to keep them).

Comment: your expected output raise a syntax error ! do you want to create a dictionary ?

Answer (score 1):

```
array(["'sf64user_Number__c':'tKey'",
 "'PreferredFirstName__c':'tPreferredFirstName'"], dtype=object)
```

is an array of 'objects', though the objects look like strings.

```
['sf64user_Number__c':'tKey', 'PreferredFirstName__c':'tPreferredFirstName']
```

does not look like a valid array, or list.  But a dictionary might print as:

```
{'sf64user_Number__c':'tKey', 'PreferredFirstName__c':'tPreferredFirstName'}
```

A dictionary wrapped in an array (with shape `()`) might print as

```
array({'sf64user_Number__c':'tKey',
 'PreferredFirstName__c':'tPreferredFirstName'}, dtype=object)
```

while an array with 2 dictionaries as:

```
array([{'sf64user_Number__c':'tKey'},
 {'PreferredFirstName__c':'tPreferredFirstName'}], dtype=object)
```

You may need to elaborate on how this array was generated.